# jenkinsfile use findFiles to get contents of a sub directory

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use findFiles to list the contents of a sub-directory, but I'm running into some issues

How can I get the contents of a subdirectory
tried

```
def files = findFiles(glob: "dirname/**")
```

but that never ends

tried

```
dir("dirname") {
    def files = findFiles()
}
```

this fails because it needs write permission on the parent directory as it tries to create dirname@tmp . It works if I relax permissions on the parent directory, but I'd really like to avoid jenkins having write permissions on that parent directory

I'm also trying to see how findFiles works by testing it in the Script console

```
def files = findFiles() 
println(files)
```

there I get

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.findFiles() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find()
```

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/ is installed, the findFiles works inside my build job

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following.

```
dir('YOUR_DIR') {
  def fileList = findFiles(glob: '*.*')
  echo "$fileList"
}
```

Comment: The glob is not needed, see my question. I'm looking for a way to achieve this *without* enclosing it in `dir() {}`